# How to install Ansible Tower?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, ansible-tower

I'm installing Ansible Tower, but when running command:
`ansible-playbook -i inventory install.yml` I receive the error shown below.

`TASK [local_docker : Start the containers] **************************************************************
fatal: [node1@node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error connecting: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such file or directory'))"}`

Could the modules used in AWX be the problem?

New error:

`TASK [local_docker : Start the containers] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: The 'docker_service' module has been renamed to 'docker_compose'.. This feature will be removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False
 in ansible.cfg.
fatal: [node1@node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "errors": [], "module_stderr": "Creating awx_memcached ... \r\nCreating awx_rabbitmq  ... \r\nCreating awx_postgres  ... \r\n\r\u001b[3BCreating awx_web       ... \r\n\r\u001b[1B", "module_stdout": "Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/memcached ... \nalpine: Pulling from docker.io/library/memcached\nDigest: sha256:32b7f473564fc8b38dbc37d9e90e36d36833f103f057fd16baf1d431361d4b34\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/memcached:alpine\nTrying to pull repository docker.io/library/postgres ... \n10: Pulling from docker.io/library/postgres\nDigest: sha256:9ee979b15082e0bd9526fde1717ffea0059e3bad936d5be9e9e5f3404f5d9375\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/postgres:10\nTrying to pull repository docker.io/ansible/awx_rabbitmq ... \n3.7.4: Pulling from docker.io/ansible/awx_rabbitmq\nDigest: sha256:3ff448f979149a0684c61b0f00eb0fe7bc480b123323aa80fb3bb8934027f895\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/ansible/awx_rabbitmq:3.7.4\nTrying to pull repository docker.io/ansible/awx_web ... \n7.0.0: Pulling from docker.io/ansible/awx_web\nDigest: sha256:4204b802a37bd7cf5389ca775aff0de3780e11e3a964b1c110efebee1f9a07e7\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/ansible/awx_web:7.0.0\nTrying to pull repository docker.io/ansible/awx_task ... \n7.0.0: Pulling from docker.io/ansible/awx_task\nDigest: sha256:481ba73fcd9141e8be6462e29fb58f0da7f9ddf3952af57b3567ae5102939151\nStatus: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/ansible/awx_task:7.0.0\n", "msg": "Error starting project unknown cause"}`

Answer (score 0):

Is docker installed on the host?
Can you try to connect on the hosts and start the container manually do you get the same error?
Can we see the task that is failing ?

Comment: 1. Docker service was not active

2. Needed to be run as root (`become: yes`)

3. Had to use `pip install docker-compose` not `python3 -m pip install docker-compose`

But it still failed to pull image from `docker.io`

Comment: Thx ! It seems that Ansible can't access docker service , can you copy/past the task that is failing ? Altough  it might be a misconfiguration of the host